# Why would gnus be so much slower to send an email than compose-mail?

Tags: email, emacs, gnus

I use Gnus v5.13 and BBDB version 3.2 under GNU Emacs 27.1.
BBDB is configured to create new entries only when I send a new message:

```
   (require 'bbdb)
   (bbdb-initialize 'gnus 'message)
   (bbdb-mua-auto-update-init 'message) 
   (setq  
     bbdb-mua-auto-update-p 'query
     bbdb-message-caching-enabled t
     )
```

Sending emails using gnus-group-mail or compose-mail take radically distinct times:

- gnus-group-mail (20 to 40s)
- compose-mail (<1s)

I could reconfigure "m" and "r" in Gnus to point to 'compose-mail' rather than 'gnus-group-mail', but I am curious as to **what could make Gnus so slow**?

- I thought that it could it be bbdb, so I changed '(bbdb-mua-auto-update-init 'message)' to '(bbdb-mua-auto-update-init nil)' to no avail...
- I thought that it could be the "gcc" field of the email, so

  - I replaced

    (setq gnus-message-archive-group
    '((if (message-news-p)
    "sent-news"
    "sent-mail")))
  - by (the default value of the variable)

    (setq      gnus-message-archive-group '((format-time-string "sent.%Y-%m")))
  - The delay vanished, but I have no idea why the former would take so long!